# mean.io vs cleverstack. Which is better

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean.io

I have to choose a framework that has angular and nodejs. I came across mean.io but the main contributor left it. mean.js is still not fully developed.
Cleverstack promises a lot but i am surprised to see very less stars and forks on github and just 2 contributors and 2 forks.
I want to know which is better to choose considering future development for my project.

Comment: I a surprised that i am given negative votes for this question. Any specific reasons?

Comment: Yep: [off-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), primarily opinion-based, which will be closed soon.

Comment: I am going to start a project based on MEAN stack and had same question about cleverstack. It looks promising but from github stats I am having doubts on whether to commit on using it for my project. Any opinions on this are most welcome.

Comment: @JeffryHouser  IMHO it's a good question to discuss pros & cons of both frameworks. Also please let me point out that you are not professional user of node.js (in accordance with your profiles).

Comment: This is really good question..wonder why its closed...

Comment: All the good stuff on stackoverflow is closed by the SO-apparatchiks who have nothing better to do than monitor your valid questions

Comment: I'm tired of idiots on SO closing good questions when they don't understand or use the related technology! I don't care if the answers are opinion based on expert experience - that's what I'm looking for! I will do my due diligence to uncover the facts after I get an insight into people's opinions.

Comment: Opinion-based, but still important.  Here is my attempt to answer the question.  Including thousands of pros and cons, I think it is the most exhaustive, unbiased and usable analysis of these things among many others.  http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/